# Android dagger how to hide generated factory classes from consuming module

Tags: android, dagger

Is there a way to hide dagger generated factory classes from consuming app?

I have a library module with its own component and consuming app obvisouly can see all the dagger generated class(e.g. LibraryData_factory.java) from the library module. But I just want to provide some public class to the consuming app and hide the rest of them, for example:

```
internal interface Person
internal class Adult @Inject constructor(): Person

internal class Car(val driver: Person): Vehicle

@Module
object LibraryModule {
  @Provides fun provideCar(person: Person): Vehicle {
    return Car(person)
  }
}
```

How can I hide the generated Adult_factory class from consuming app?